# Material Design : FloatingActionButton fade in-out implementation

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I would like to implement a behavior like the following one
https://youtu.be/E1cYxg4rBIE
, taken from google material guidelines.
My project has a ViewPagerAdapter and has 3 fragments, like in the google example.

Thanks in advance for any hint that could lead me to the possible implementation!